# What does git mean "wrong number of arguments"?

Tags: git, git-config

I wanted to get all the git config entries, so I glanced over the options and found `--get-all`, but it gave:

```
C:\>git config --global --get-all
error: wrong number of arguments
usage: git config [<options>]
```

It doesn't seem to specify a number of arguments, it just says `[<options>]`.
And I don't know what other options it would need.

Comment: It means that's the... wrong number of arguments. As the help text shows, if you use `--get-all` it expects a `key` and, optionally, a `value-regex`. Did you look at [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config---get-all)?

Comment: Since your own answer doesn't answer the question you asked, you must have a different question in mind. As it stands, this question is unlikely to help anyone else, but you could edit it to reflect what you really want (that is, so your answer addresses the question actually asked, rather than the one in your head no-one else can see)

Comment: Both my question and answer were edited, removing context. And my answer did answer my question; it's just that my question was poorly formed.

Comment: I've updated the question and answer so that the problem is clear.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is there a policy on not including meta information (context) in a question? I'm fine with leaving it out if there is, but it doesn't feel nice to have part of what you wrote doubly deleted without explanation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm somewhere between beginner and intermediate at git and I find the message opaque. `--get-all             get all values: key [value-regex]` It's not all that clear what `key` means unless you already know how config organizes keys.  Fortunately  `-l, --list` is not too much farther down and does what `--get-all` sounds like it might do (but doesn't).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For viewing the entire config, the correct argument is `--list`, not `--get-all`
(or you may also want `--edit`).

The "number of arguments" is of *arguments to the argument* (or so to speak), *subarguments*;
it's just a really vague error message.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question. Perhaps you should include the fact that you were trying to list all global configuration options in it? If someone *is* trying to use `--get-all`, this doesn't help them at all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've updated it (and more importantly the question); the problem scenario should be clear now

Comment: `git config --local --list` was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

You have set it

```
git config --global --get-all
```

but as you can see in the help section right below

> ```
> Action
>     --get                 get value: name [value-regex]
>     --get-all             get all values: key [value-regex]
> ```

So that means you are missing the `key` argument and optionally the `value-regex` argument.

You can read more about it in [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config---get-all).

Answer (score 1):

Only use double quotes.

Example:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory "D:/WORK/Angular Projects/website/panelapp"
```